# About android firebase chat push notification

Tags: android

I'm doing a chat app between 2 devices with push notification by using firebase...Whenever I'm registering both devices getting registered with their corresponding token..suppose if I'm sending notification from device A to device B means device B receiving notification without any problem...But while sending from device B to Device A ,that device A  is not receiving the notification....Where I'm doing mistake???

Here device A is samsung

Device B is Motorola

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please Show your code

Comment: lot of class files are there

Comment: code in which you are sending notification from device B To A

Comment: now its working  for me by adding following line in manifest               <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />